# find ip addresses that appear more than so many times during the same day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns - date_time and ip_address.  I want to be able to identify ip addresses that appear more than 10 times per day.  I can't figure out how to extract the date only from the date_time column and run this query, this is what I've tried:

```
    SELECT ip_address, date(date_time) as date, count(date) as cnt FROM ip_tracking GROUP BY date_time, ip_address HAVING cnt > 10 ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

I get #1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'.  Do I need to create a column at the beginning of the query?

Thanks

Comment: Change `count(date)` to `count(1)`

Comment: You get the date, but then group by (and order by) date_time, same for the COUNT (you are counting an alias rather than a field). If date can't be null then you can just use COUNT(*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access alias of an expression in the same level. Instead use the same expression with `'count'`.

And I believe you want to `count` by `date` but not `date_time`.

```
SELECT ip_address
     , date(date_time) as date
     , count( date( date_time ) ) as cnt 
FROM ip_tracking 
GROUP BY date( date_time ), ip_address 
HAVING cnt > 10 
ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, seems so simple when you know!  If I wanted to identify ip addresses that appear more than 10 times in a minute would that be possible?  Would I need to remove the seconds from the date_time eg 2014-03-31 21:04:26 would need to become 2014-03-31 21:04:00.

Comment: You can count based on date with hour & minute including, but omitting seconds part.

Answer (score 0):

Using the date for the group by (you can use the alias for that), and using COUNT(*) (rather than having an alias within the count).

```
SELECT ip_address,
     date(date_time) as date,
     count( * ) as cnt 
FROM ip_tracking 
GROUP BY date, ip_address 
HAVING cnt > 10 
ORDER BY date DESC
```